# How small can a NFA be, compared to the minimal Unambiguous Finite Automaton (UFA) of the same regular language?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, regular-language

Unambiguous Finite Automatons (UFA) are special type of non-deterministic finite automatons (NFA).

A NFA is called *unambiguous* if every word $w\in \Sigma^*$ has at most one accepting path.

This means $DFA\subset UFA\subset NFA$.

Known related automaton results:

> 1. NFA minimization is PSPACE-Complete.
> 2. [NFA minimization over finite languages is DP-Hard](http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~gruberh/data/lata07-submission.pdf).
> 3. [UFA minimization is NP-Complete](http://lrb.cs.uni-dortmund.de/~martens/data/icalp08talk.pdf).
> 4. [There exists NFAs which are exponentially smaller than minimal DFAs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3381/nfa-with-exponential-number-of-states-when-deteminized).
>      (Also - there exists UFAs which are exponentially smaller than minimal DFAs - R B).

The question is: can we find a regular language $L$ such that the there exists a NFA accepting $L$ which is exponentially smaller (state-wise) than the minimal **UFA** for $L$?
Can this happen for a finite language?

I believe such (finite) $L$ exists, but my proof currently relies on the Exponential Time Hypothesis to hold, and was wondering if someone has a proof which doesn't rely on it.

Also, can someone characterize the set of languages for which such size difference exist?

EDIT: @Shaull gave a nice link to a paper dealing with infinite language. Does anyone know a similar result for a finite language?

Comment: If you haven't looked at it yet, Colcombet has a really nice survey on related concepts: http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~colcombe/Publications/STACS12-colcombet.pdf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the IJFCS'05 paper by Leung: [Descriptional complexity of nfa of different ambiguity](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S0129054105003418)
provides an example with a family of NFA accepting finite languages that involve an exponential blowup for "disambiguation" (in the proof of Theorem 5).

What is more, those automata have a special structure (DFA with multiple initial states).

Answer (score 17):

There is even a stronger result than your request:

There are exponentially-ambiguous NFAs for which the minimal polynomially-ambiguous NFAs are exponentially larger, and in particular the minimal UFAs.

Check [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=284965) by Hing Leung.

Comment: Thanks @Shaull.

Do you know if a similar result exists for finite languages?

Comment: I am not aware of any similar results for finite languages, sorry.