# Converting 2-ambiguous NFA to unambiguous NFA

Tags: automata-theory, regular-language, nondeterminism, nfa, ambiguity

This must be known, but somehow I can't locate a reference about this. Let $A$ be a [nondeterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) (NFA) over words of an alphabet $\Sigma$. I say that $A$ is *[unambigous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unambiguous_finite_automaton)* if, for every word $w \in \Sigma^*$, then $A$ has at most one accepting run over $w$. I say that $A$ is *2-ambiguous* if, for every word $w \in \Sigma^*$, then $A$ has at most two accepting runs over $w$.

**Can I transform in polynomial time an input 2-ambiguous NFA into an unambiguous NFA which is equivalent?** (i.e., recognizes the same language) **Or is it known that it is not possible?** e.g., there is a family of 2-ambiguous NFAs where the number of states of any equivalent unambiguous NFAs must be exponential?

In terms of related work, I found the 1989 SIAM J. Comput. paper by Ravikumar and Ibarra *[Relating the type of ambiguity of finite automata to the succinctness of their representation](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0218083)* (unfortunately I didn't find an open-access version) which shows that, given a $k$-ambiguous NFA, there is an exponential blowup in $k$ to convert it to an unambiguous NFA. But this does not imply anything for $k=2$. I also found lots of works about more exotic automata models. But I guess the result on vanilla NFAs must be known (or simple to show)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that **this is in fact not possible**, thanks to the (recent and difficult!) [ICALP'22 results of Göös et al.](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2022/16467/).

They show that there are UFAs $A_1$ and $A_2$ with $n$ states such that the language $L = L(A_1) \cup L(A_2)$ is not recognized by a UFA of polynomial size in $n$.

However, from two such UFAs $A_1$ and $A_2$, you can construct a 2-UFA $A$ recognizing $L(A_1)$ and $L(A_2)$, simply by taking their disjoin union and keeping as initial states the initial states of $A_1$ and $A_2$. Then $A$ clearly recognizes $L(A_1) \cup L(A_2)$, and $A$ is a 2-UFA because for every run you have at most one run in the $A_1$ part and at most one run in the $A_2$ part given that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are UFAs. The result of Göös et al. implies that $A$ has no equivalent UFA of polynomial size, which a putative PTIME 2-UFA to UFA conversion algorithm would compute.

As a side remark, $k$-UFAs for fixed $k$ are not so badly behaved, as you can count how many words they accept, and solve inclusion and containment for them in PTIME. This is in [Stearns and Hunt, SIAM J. Comput., 1985](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0214044). There are similar results for $k$-ambiguous tree automata, in [Seidl, SIAM J. Comput., 1990](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0219027). (Unfortunately, no open-access versions of these papers that I can see.)

Comment: Interesting result! I wonder whether this construction can be reversed: Can every $k$-UFA language $L$ be expressed as the union of $k$ $1$-UFA languages $L=L_1\cup L_2\cup\cdots \cup L_k$? My guess would be: probably not.

Comment: I do not think this reversed result has been studied for unambiguity but similar results exists for non-determinism, see e.g. Martin Sauerhoff:
*Guess-and-verify versus unrestricted nondeterminism for OBDDs and one-way Turing machines.* J. Comput. Syst. Sci. 66(3): 473-495 (2003)

Comment: Interesting question! (Of course I guess "can be expressed" means "with a polynomial-time translation", as otherwise you can always express any regular language with a single UFA with an exponential blowup.) I don't know, and as @holf points out I guess you could ask a similar question on decision diagrams: can you efficiently rewrite uOBDDs (OBDDs with unambiguous disjunction) so that the disjunctions are at the top level?